# How to get the transformation matrix of the camera in rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

When we using left mouse, to change the view angle in Rviz, then is this possible, to get the orientation of that view.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9973/how-to-get-the-transformation-matrix-of-the-camera-in-rviz?/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-05-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-17**:
Are you asking how to get the transformation matrix of the camera that rviz is using to view from a specific location? Also I think you have a typo in your title. I think you meant to have a "get the" before "orientation", and a '?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz does not expose the pose of the viewpoint camera.  If you're interested in this feature, you can file a feature request in trac. You find a link on the bottom of the wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/visualization

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ticket has been filed by someone else who wants this feature:

[rviz camera: getting and setting the viewpoint](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5166)

I expect we'll get it implemented in the next few weeks.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1